# Angular 4 Reactive Form Validator Required shows error on touch when value is preset

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

The issue I am having is that the form is showing an error for an input field. I don't know why it is showing and its probably due to a lack of understanding. So I have a component called edit team. Inside this edit team component I have an input field with a value that is set to the current team name. If I put focus on the input text field and then remove focus to lets say the background then the form triggers a "required" error even with the value preset and unchanged.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input tabindex="0" type="text" placeholder="Please enter the team name" title="Please enter the team name" required value=""
               id="name" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name" [value]="nameValue">

    // This is the condition for when the error is shown. 
    // So when the input field is touched, check if an error 
    // exists for the validator required. 
    <div class='form-text error' *ngIf="editTeamFormGroup.controls.name.touched">
        <div *ngIf="editTeamFormGroup.controls.name.hasError('required')" class="help-block error small">Team name is required.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the constructor and the ngOnIt method for the component. The subscription is for an observable within the team service, when the team changes so do the values.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private teamService: TeamService,
              private router: Router,
              public modalService: ModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.teamService.teamChange.subscribe(result => {
      this.team = result;
      this.nameValue = this.team.name;
      this.descriptionValue = this.team.description;
    });


    this.editTeamFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      'name': [ this.nameValue, Validators.required ],
      'description': [ this.descriptionValue, Validators.required ]
    });
  }
```

Note: No errors within the console. The validation works as expected if I add characters to the preset value and change focus to another element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the way you setup the form. As `this.teamService.teamChange` is asynchronous, you cannot guarantee `this.nameValue` is setup **before** `this.editTeamFormGroup` is created.

If you wait until you get necessary information then initiate the form group, thing will be working properly. And don't use `[value]` together with `formControlName` in `<input>` unless you have a good reason to.

Template

```
<form [formGroup]="editTeamFormGroup" *ngIf="editTeamFormGroup">
... 
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input tabindex="0" type="text" placeholder="Please enter the team name" title="Please enter the team name" required value=""
               id="name" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name">

</form>
```

Code behind

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.teamService.teamChange.subscribe(result => {
      this.team = result;
      this.nameValue = this.team.name;
      this.descriptionValue = this.team.description;

      this.editTeamFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        'name': [ this.nameValue, Validators.required ],
        'description': [ this.descriptionValue, Validators.required ]
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: My reactive form shows validation errors on untouched fields. How can I solve this ? Anything idea ?